# Jira escape button behaviour

Tags: events, escaping, field, jira

I am currently working with Jira and stumbled on a problem. If on the browse page of an issue and editing a textfield, pressing escape discards all changes. Doing the same editing a comment field, doesn't discard changes on the comment. What I really want is that changes will be saved when pressing escape and losing focus on editing the field content. The same that happens if you click in an empty area.

Of course I am not the only one searching for a solution to this problem:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-36670

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41814

Now I am not here to discuss the meaning of the escape button. There are several reasons for the behaviour i wish (start with reading the comments on the first link).

Is there any way to edit Keyevent handling of jira? Or overwrite event behaviour of standard fields? Adding events via browser plugins or similar doesn't help as the content is already lost then.

I hope there is some elegant solution out there as I am not the only searching for one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athlassian really did it with the Esc-behavior. It costs people nerves and money. Esc shouldn't save anything IMHO but it should at least offer you the possibility of retreiving the lost work. Jira-Description might get realy big and if you don't save you lose your temper and resources.

There is a nice workaround though. I found it in [Jira-Development Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-36670?focusedCommentId=771996&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-771996) :)

### The workaround:

1. Install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en)
2. Open any of your JIRA pages, click the "CJS" icon in the toolbar
3. Paste this snippet

   `document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e)
   {
       var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
       if (charCode == 27)
       {
           alert("Please do not press escape.")
       }
   });
   document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
       var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
       if (charCode == 27){
           alert("Please do not press escape.")
       }
   });`

Now you will get an alert every time the escape key is pressed and the content will be preserved.

Comment: Work for me for the Escape! Happy now :) Now need to find/code how to stop the Cancel from doing the same. Annoyed when mouse goes to Cancel instead Save. Maybe should use Alt+s to save instead mouse :)

Comment: So adding something with greasemonkey it is. Doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution, but it is one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should save edits when pressing escape. Its pretty intuitive to abort an action by pressing esc. You will confuse your users. They will make changes to their issues, they didn't wanted to do.

This behavior is discussed here:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-36670

You are right - Comments are saved after pressing escape, but this behavior might change very soon: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41814

**What you can do**:

- You could write your own plugin, and attach a javascript event
  listener to your issue view.
- When you press Esc, copy the content of the description field.
- Use JIRA rest services to update your issue wit the text you copied from the description field.

  But as I said - this is messy and you should not do it.